# How to access same resource from multiple objects?

Tags: c++, class, object, driver, hardware

I am relatively new to C++ OOP, so please be patient with me.

I am using a 3rd party drivers for CAN bus protocol that's implemented for dedicated hardware (PCIE module). It comes with a class that allows you to instantiate `can_read` and `can_write` objects.

This library is used in my own program where I have a class and 7 instances of the aforementioned class that need access the `can_write` object which is defined in a global scope in the main file.

The issue I am having is the `can_write` object. As its a driver level library it's accessing the same memory address from the `can_write` object. If I have a member function that takes `can_writer` by value, the program crashes whenever it's accessed with "double free or corruption" error.

I am now passing the `can_writer` object by reference ("CanClass &a" for the argument) and it seems to work, however I am not sure if that's a good practice or a conventional way of doing it. Is that the right way of doing it? If not, what is the right way? Any references or even a brief explanation would be really helpful!

EDIT: I must avoid creating copies of `can_writer` as it will read to memory corruption, hence all 7 instances of my `Class Foo` need to access the exact same instance of `can_write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variation of a singleton pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) on your class.

For example, you could have a get_can_write() method that check if a can_write object is instantiated, if so a reference to this object is returned, otherwise it creates an object can_write, keeps a reference to it and returns it.

Your class that provides can_write and can_read would look like this :

```cpp
class Bar {
private:
    static can_write* cw;
    static can_read* cr;

public:
    static can_write* get_can_write(){
        if(cw == null)
            cw = new can_write;
        return cw;
    }

    static can_read* get_can_read(){
        if(cr == null)
            cr = new can_read;
        return cr;
    }
}
```

And the classes that use can_write and can_read would look like :

```cpp
class Foo{
public:
    void doSomeRead(){
        string s = Bar::get_can_read()->doSomething();
    }

    void doSomeWrite(){
        Bar::get_can_write()->doSomething("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you elaborate a bit further please, how would this solve the problem? Every 'can_write' object will be accessing the same memory address, I want to have all 7 objects of mine to access that one, same object.

Comment: I just edited my answer to add some examples how you could do that.

Comment: Note that your getters return pointers, so `->` is needed to acesss members

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my answer to be more reliable.

Comment: Hi, I don't think I have made myself exactly clear. Can_writer will be accessing the same registers of the hardware module, having multiple instances of it results in module errors and memory errors, I want to use the same object from 7 objects of my own.

Comment: You can just duplicate the second code in multiple classes to access the same can_write object.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. What if I used pass by reference instead of Singletons? Is that a bad practice?